# Creating objects with JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

Using an API, I am calling for an options chain with lots of different data. It looks like this:

````
```
[
  putCall=PUT
  symbol=AAPL_012023P100
  description=AAPL Jan 20 2023 100 Put
  exchangeName=OPR
  bidPrice=10.05
  askPrice=10.3
  lastPrice=10.15
  bidAskSize=78X102
  markPrice=10.18
  bidSize=78
  askSize=102
  lastSize=0
  highPrice=10.15
  lowPrice=9.85
  openPrice=0.0
  closePrice=9.98
  totalVolume=334
  quoteTimeInLong=1612904400035
  tradeTimeInLong=1612903831902
  netChange=0.17
  volatility=37.645
  delta=-0.195
  gamma=0.004
  theta=-0.014
  vega=0.524
  rho=-0.676
  timeValue=10.15
  openInterest=7941
  isInTheMoney=false
  theoreticalOptionValue=10.175
  theoreticalVolatility=29.0
  isMini=false
  isNonStandard=false
  optionDeliverablesList=<null>
  strikePrice=100.0
  expirationDate=1674248400000
  expirationType=R
  multiplier=100.0
  settlementType= 
  deliverableNote=
  isIndexOption=<null>
  percentChange=1.75
  markChange=0.2
  markPercentChange=2.01
  otherFields={lastTradingDay=1674262800000, daysToExpiration=709, tradeDate=null}
]], ```
````

This is one part of the many it returns. I need all of them. So, using Jackson I understand how to convert this to JSON using something like this:

````
```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String data = eq.toString();
    mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(data);
````

Now, this cleans it up some, but now for what I actually need.. I need 3 things out of all this. I would like to create an object for each one of these things with the following fields: openInterest, totalVolume, and description.

I have tried searching for this, but I can't figure it out for when you have multiple values. What I posted above is just one of many entries that the API returns me. I would really appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
[
  putCall=PUT
  symbol=AAPL_012023P100

  /*bla di bla whatever*/

  markPercentChange=2.01
  otherFields={lastTradingDay=1674262800000, daysToExpiration=709, tradeDate=null}
]], ``
```

I'ma call this `leSRC`

```
  JSONObject zTHING = new JSONObject();

  zTHING.put("openInterest", leSRC.getJSONObject("openInterest"));
  zTHING.put("totalVolume",  leSRC.getJSONObject("totalVolume"));
  zTHING.put("description",  leSRC.getJSONObject("description"));
```

Your `zTHING` object should have those 3 KvP's set up correctly.

Comment: Okay thanks. How do I do it with multiple entries though? Like say that list of info I gave is 1/50 things in it. I would like to create 50 objects with those fields.